# Testing for IE7+ javascript plugins

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, oop, plugins

```
(function (window, undefined){
var _eles = [],
    _target, source, mobile, destory;
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function (classname) {
        var elArray = [];
        var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classname + "(\\s|$)");
        for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            if (regex.test(tmp[i].className)) {
                elArray.push(tmp[i]);
            }
        }
        return elArray;
    };
}
//if ((/msie 7/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
//  console.log('true')
//}
var uTube = {
    init: function (opts) {
        var nodes = ["www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "youtu.be/", "www.youtube.com/embed/", "www.youtube.com/v/", "youtube.com/watch?feature"],
            vers = opts.version,
            i;
        switch (vers) {
        case "phpbb3":
            vers = 'content';
            break;
        case "phpbb2":
            vers = 'postbody';
            break;
        case "punbb":
            vers = 'entry-content';
            break;
        case "invision":
            vers = 'postbody';
            break;
        }
        _target = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
        for (i = 0; i < _target.length; i++) {
            _eles.push(_target[i].getElementsByClassName(vers));
        }
        console.log(_eles);
        return {
            source: function (opt) {
                console.log(_eles);
            },
            mobile: function (opt) {
                console.log('we are now' + opt.text);
                return {
                    destroy: function () {
                        console.log('destroyed');
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
};
return (window.utube = window._$ = uTube.init);
})(window);
```

I am trying to find a way to test my code on browsers that may not support some of my methods. for when I try in IE7 and 8 I get an error saying `Unable to get property 'mobile' of undefined or null reference`

Code Initiation looks like this:

```
_$({
    version:"phpbb3"
  }).mobile({text:"mobile version"}).destroy();
```

Right now the properties are just logging certain things for testing purposes. Though like I said it's not working in IE7 or 8, haven't tested 9 yet until 7 and 8 are done.  Is there something in particular that I should change for IE7+ in my code that you can see off hand if not is there a site that can give me a close range of what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks to @RobertLevy I fixed a major issue of the break and returns. Though I am figuring out the best method of getElementsByClassName of the object as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to put `break` instead of `return` in the switch blocks.

Comment: oops that was one mistake such a silly mistake on my behalf I'll fix this, just was writing a lot of returns haha